# findUnique query returns null for array fields

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2, graphql-playground

I read the [Prisma Relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#many-to-many-relations) documentation and it fixed my `findMany` query which is able to return valid data but I'm getting inconsistent results with findUnique.

**Schema**

```
model User {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  fname    String
  lname    String
  email    String
  password String
  vehicles Vehicle[]
}

model Vehicle {
  id      Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  vin     String @unique
  model   String
  make    String
  drivers User[]
}
```

**Typedefs**

```
const typeDefs = gql'
    type User {
      id: ID!
      fname: String
      lname: String
      email: String
      password: String
      vehicles: [Vehicle]
    }

    type Vehicle {
      id: ID!
      vin: String
      model: String
      make: String
      drivers: [User]
    }

    type Mutation {
      post(id: ID!, fname: String!, lname: String!): User
    }

    type Query {
      users: [User]
      user(id: ID!): User
      vehicles: [Vehicle]
      vehicle(vin: String): Vehicle
    }
'
```

**This one works**

```
users: async (_, __, context) => {
        return context.prisma.user.findMany({
          include: { vehicles: true}
        })
      },
```

However, for some reason the findUnique version will not resolve the array field for "vehicles"

**This one doesn't work**

```
user: async (_, args, context) => {
     const id = +args.id
     return context.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: {id} }, 
         include: { vehicles: true}
     )
},
```

**This is what it returns**

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "id": "1",
      "fname": "Jess",
      "lname": "Potato",
      "vehicles": null
    }
  }
}
```

I was reading about fragments and trying to find documentation on graphql resolvers but I haven't found anything relevant that can solve this issue.

Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the arguments passed to `findUnique`. Notice the arrangement of the `{` and `}`.

Change

```
return context.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id } },
  //                                                  ^
  include: { vehicles: true}
)
```

to

```
return context.prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: { id }, 
  include: { vehicles: true }
})
```

Comment: You have no idea how many hours I've been at this. THANK YOU!!